# Remove routerLinkActive with two classes when the user go to another menu

Tags: angular

I'm doing a Web Application with Angular 6 and I'm trying to implement routerLink and routerLinkActive. Right now, routerLink seems to work well but, `routerLinkActive` is not. It keeps the class inside the tag even if the user go to another menu.

I have followed the docs to add two classes but, one of them is not going away. I would like to remove both together, right now, `menu-open` is not going away. I have also tried: `<li class="treeview" [routerLinkActive]="['active', 'menu-open']">`

```
<li class="treeview" routerLinkActive="active menu-open">
        <a href="#">
          <i class="fa fa-cog"></i>
          <span>Administration</span>
          <span class="pull-right-container">
              <i class="fa fa-angle-left pull-right"></i>
            </span>
        </a>
        <ul class="treeview-menu">
          <li routerLinkActive="active"><a routerLink="/users-list"><i class="fa fa-group"></i> Users list</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
```

My goal is to remove correctly both classes, `active` and `menu-open`. The first one seems to be removed well but, not the second one.

Answer (score 0):

There are two nested `routerlinkActive`s in your list. The problem most probably lies there. If you want the outer `li` to have `active` class when one of its children is active, you can use template reference variable with `routerLinkActive` directive like this:

```
<li class="treeview" [ngClass]="rlRef.isActive ? 'active menu-open': ''">
        <a>
          <i class="fa fa-cog"></i>
          <span>Administration</span>
          <span class="pull-right-container">
              <i class="fa fa-angle-left pull-right"></i>
            </span>
        </a>
        <ul class="treeview-menu">
          <li [ngClass]="{'active': rlRef.isActive}">
             <a routerLink="/users-list" routerLinkActive #rlRef="routerLinkActive">
                 <i class="fa fa-group"></i> Users list
              </a>
           </li>
        </ul>
</li>
```

Note that, I removed `href="#"` from `a` tag as it reloads the whole page. And replaced the second `routerLinkActive` from `li` to `a` tag.

**Edit**

Replaced

`[ngClass]="{'active': rlRef.isActive}"`

with

`[ngClass]="rlRef.isActive ? 'active menu-open': ''"`

since `ngClass` does not work very well when assigning multiple classes in one condition.

**Edit 2**

```
<!-- Full menu -->
<ul>

    <!-- Link without child -->
    <li [ngClass]="settingsRouteRef.isActive ? 'active another-class': ''">
          <a routerLink="/settings" routerLinkActive #settingsRouteRef="routerLinkActive">
              <i class="fa fa-gears"></i>
              <span>Settings</span>
              <span class="pull-right-container">
                  <i class="fa fa-angle-left pull-right"></i>
                </span>
            </a>
    </li>


    <!-- Link with child -->
    <li class="treeview" [ngClass]="adminRouteRef.isActive ? 'active menu-open': ''">
            <a>
              <i class="fa fa-cog"></i>
              <span>Administration</span>
              <span class="pull-right-container">
                  <i class="fa fa-angle-left pull-right"></i>
                </span>
            </a>
            <ul class="treeview-menu">
              <li [ngClass]="{'active': adminRouteRef.isActive}">
                 <a routerLink="/users-list" routerLinkActive #adminRouteRef="routerLinkActive">
                     <i class="fa fa-group"></i> Users list
                  </a>
               </li>
            </ul>
    </li>

    <!-- Another Link with child -->
    <li class="treeview" [ngClass]="dashboardRouteRef.isActive ? 'active menu-open': ''">
            <a>
              <i class="fa fa-cog"></i>
              <span>Dashboard</span>
              <span class="pull-right-container">
                  <i class="fa fa-angle-left pull-right"></i>
                </span>
            </a>
            <ul class="treeview-menu">
              <li [ngClass]="{'active': dashboardRouteRef.isActive}">
                 <a routerLink="/reports" routerLinkActive #dashboardRouteRef="routerLinkActive">
                     <i class="fa fa-group"></i> Reports
                  </a>
               </li>
            </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Hi my friend, thanks for answering my question. I have a doubt, because of the design of my template that I'm using, class"active" is inside of `<li>` tag and I noticed that you added it inside of `<a>`tag. It doesn't matter? or it will change the effect of things?

Comment: You are right. I forgot to remove binding from second `routerLinkActive`. It is totally safe to remove `="active"`. I edited the answer

Comment: Right now, for some reason, Àdministration` keeps as `active` when I change the page. If I go to a menu with no child, the menu with child's keeps the active class. Any idea?.

Comment: Do you use the same template reference variable (`#rlRef`) for all the `li` elements? If so, you should use differerent (unique) fore each route, such as `#adminRouteRef`, `#settingsRouteRef` etc.

Comment: I have one `<ul>`and inside of it three `<li>` elements. Some with childs inside and others without. I can't figure out how to set them up to behave correctly when changing the router link. The thing is that, if you click on a `<li>` with childs, and you click on another menu with no childs, the original needs to remove the `active`class. should I use different reference variable for each `<li>` inside of the `<ul>`?

Comment: I improved the sample in 'Edit 2' section. Please have a look at.